# In Binary Search, why the element to be searched is not first checked if it is lesser than or greater than minimum or maximum index of array?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

When doing a Binary Search, we divide our search scope on array in half progressively and look for the desire element. If the element is not present in sorted array, we get the result only after last remaining element of array has been compared against. Why not just use a simple statement like:

```
def binarySearch(array,element):
        maxIndex=len(array)-1

       if(array[maxIndex]<element):
                return -1
       if(array[0]>element):
                return -1
```

Basically, why not compare against the minimum and maximum value of sorted array first to check for presence of the element in array.

It might even not be present in array even then, but we still save a lot of searching if the element is greater or lesser than any element of array.

Comment: This might make sense if the probability of finding the element you are looking for is known to be very low.

Comment: @500 While true, how much does this affect the performance, specially considering that we might not always know either the element is in the array. It is not hard to come up wit, so there must be a specific reason this is not in the standard implementation of Binary Search

Comment: A binary search doesn't require a completely sorted input, it's sufficient for it to be partitioned on the value you're searching for.  That means the first and last element needn't be the min and max.

Answer (score 1):

In a binary search the number of comparisons is about 1+log<sub>2</sub>n, assuming an algorithm that performs just one comparison per iteration (so no equality check), and one final comparison to see if the only remaining candidate value is a match.

If indeed the searched value is out of the data set's outer limits, then your proposal will reduce the number of comparisons to 1 or 2 (depending on which side the outlier is -- let's say the probability is equally distributed). The downside is that you now *increase* the number of comparisons with 2 for values that are *inside* those limits. And so it might turn out that on *average* you actually lose more than you gain. This depends on the probability of getting a search value that is within the limits  (not necessarily a match).

Let's call *P* the probability to get a value that is *outside* the boundaries. If that probability is high then the average number of comparisons  will be lower than with the standard algorithm. But if the probability is not high enough, then the average number of comparisons will be higher than in the standard algorithm.

If you know both the probability involved and the size of your binary tree, then you can decide based on an easy arithmetic formula which of the two algorithms is the best:

- Standard algorithm: *1 + log<sub>2</sub>n* expected comparisons
- Your proposal: *1.5*P + (1-P)*(3 + log<sub>2</sub>n)* expected comparisons. Note the 3 which includes the 2 extra comparisons.

So just plug in your actual values for *n* and *P*, and you can check which algorithm will on average perform fewer comparisons.

Comment: For n=1,000,000 & P=0.5;
Standard  Algorithm takes 21 comparisons;
Proposed Algorithm takes 12 comparisons

Comment: Indeed, 50% is a high percentage. So then it's absolutely worth it.

Comment: By running further calculations: for n=1000 Proposed algo gets faster at P>17%; for n=1 million at P>9%; for n=1 billion at P>6%; for n=1 trillion at P>4%

Comment: Yes. It all depends what the actual situation is. If the values that ended up in the tree had the same probability distribution as the lookup value, then P would be much smaller.